# Why doesn't my Imagemagick convert consider the loop parameter?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using this command:

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 1 -density 300 myfile.pdf myfile.gif
```

on Windows 10 and all works well except for the loop parameter: even if I set it to `1`, I always get an infinite loop.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some experiments varying the `-loop` parameter from 0 through 3 and using a simple red frame followed by a blue frame as follows:

```
for i in 0 1 2 3; do 
   echo i=$i
   ((d=80+i))
   convert -delay $d -loop $i -size 256x256 xc:red xc:blue a.gif
   identify -verbose a.gif | grep -E "Iter|Delay"
done
```

**Results**

```
i=0
  Delay: 80x100
  Iterations: 0
  Delay: 80x100
  Iterations: 0
i=1
  Delay: 81x100
  Delay: 81x100
i=2
  Delay: 82x100
  Iterations: 2
  Delay: 82x100
  Iterations: 2
i=3
  Delay: 83x100
  Iterations: 3
  Delay: 83x100
  Iterations: 3
```

So, it seems that the `-delay` parameter and `-loop` parameter **ARE** correctly set in the GIF file, although the `-loop` is omitted if it is `1` which is the default anyway.

I then looked at my animated GIF in OSX using the `quicklook` feature where you tap the <kbd>␣</kbd> (SPACEBAR) in **Finder** and it does not respect the `-loop` setting, however, if you open the GIF in **Safari** or **Firefox** it does respect the setting, so I am guessing it is not very standardised and whatever you are using to view the GIF files is not compliant with the poorly-followed standard.

I may be wrong but try using a different viewer such as Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I've opened it with Internet Explorer and it works, while with "Foto" (I don't know the English name, I think it is the program that Windows 10 automatically associates to the .gif files) it doesn't!