# PIL is showing all the previous frames in the gif

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif

```
pillow version:5.4.1
```

The problem is I can see all the frames in the gif.

**Expectation**: in the lifecycle of a gif having 5 frames each frames should be visible for a fraction of time and at the end of gif only 5th frame should be visible.

**Actual**: In my case at the end of the gif I can see all the frames 1-2-3-4-5.

There are 5 frames in the gif animation and all the frames are in gif format(static) I also tried with png files too but I am getting the same result.

All my frames are with transparent background.

```
from PIL import Image

frame_list = []
frame_list.append("object_1.gif")
frame_list.append("object_2.gif")
frame_list.append("object_3.gif")
frame_list.append("object_4.gif")
frame_list.append("object_5.gif")

images = []
for n in frame_list:
    frame = Image.open(n)
    images.append(frame)

images[0].save('anitest.gif',
               save_all=True,
               format='GIF',
               append_images=images[1:],
               duration=200,
               loop=0)
```

If anyone encountered the same issue please let me know what am I doing wrong?

[image]

**With the below code using imageio it's working but I am loosing transparency and its very slow compare PIL**

```
images = []
for filename in names:
    images.append(imageio.imread(filename))
imageio.mimsave('anitest.gif', images,duration=0.3)
```

Comment: It may be your browser, try using a different program to view it... https://stackoverflow.com/a/40442936/2836621

Comment: I did not check it on browser but after your suggestion I checked it on browser but I am getting the same result.

Comment: Can you share the GIF?

Comment: Added the gif ! I have increased the loop just to show what is going wrong.

Comment: I can see what the problem is - it is not clearing between the frames so the *"disposal"* is not set correctly. I am experimenting with `save(..., disposal=N)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the *"disposal"* is not being set correctly. Try with:

```
images[0].save('anitest.gif',
               save_all=True,
               format='GIF',
               append_images=images[1:],
               duration=200,disposal=2,
               loop=0)
```

[image]

Comment: How does `disposal` parameter exactly work?

Comment: @ValentinPopescu There's a first-rate description here https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/

Comment: @ValentinPopescu More here https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/

Comment: @ValentinPopescu Even more... https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/