# Frames of transparent gif overlapping with each other

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, animated-gif, alpha-transparency

I'm trying to create a transparent gif through pillow in python through this code

```
frames[0].save(path+'/final.gif', format='GIF', append_images=frames[1:], save_all=True, duration=33, loop=0,transparency=0)
```

where frame is a list of PIL.Image files. The end result is that you can see the image in the previous frame[image]

This hasn't happened before and I was able to create this gif without any problems
[image]

Comment: Try setting the *"disposal"* like here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/55314160/2836621

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by setting `disposal = 2` , you can edit your code as:

```
frames[0].save(path+'/final.gif', format='GIF', append_images=frames[1:], save_all=True, duration=33, loop=0,transparency=0, disposal = 2)
```