# Python PIL : Frames of transparent gif when resized, are overlapping with each other even when (disposal = 2)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, animated-gif

I am using python Pillow to resize a transparent GIF [[code here]](https://repl.it/@TheViralClovers/gifResizerpy), [[gif here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwtV0.gif) however once i resize the gif, the previous frames overlap, i dont want it to, and i want to know why it is happening and how i can prevent it

***What is the code supposed to do?***

According to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58997648/frames-of-transparent-gif-overlapping-with-each-other) , the overlapping frames are supposed to be removed, by using (disposal = 2)

***What is your code doing instead?***

its giving the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I75ju.jpg) as a gif with overlapping frames

There is no error message

***What have you tried?***

i have tried to use disposal as 0,1 and 2 [[output here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I75ju.jpg) , still wont remove the overlapping images

***what queries have you searched?***

I have looked through these stackoverflow answers

[1)resizing a transparent gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58997648/frames-of-transparent-gif-overlapping-with-each-other) [soln did not work]

[2)PIL is showing previous images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313887/pil-is-showing-all-the-previous-frames-in-the-gif/55314160#55314160) [soln did not work]

[3)Pillow resizing a gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718892/pillow-resizing-a-gif)

​

Then i read Docs on [pillow here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageSequence.html#extracting-frames-from-an-animation), however i am still not able to understand why my code didn't work,any help is greatly appreciated