# How to get full frames correctly for difference-based GIFs using Python Imageio?

Tags: python, image, gif, animated-gif, python-imageio

GIFs are images that can be animated, i.e. consist of a sequence of frames. There are two types of GIFs in the world: Type A stores each frame separately, and type B **instead stores the differences between subsequent GIFs**.

I am loading GIFs using `imageio` which works fine for type A but only returns differences for type B. How can I easily get the full frames instead?

This is how I get the images:

```
reader = imageio.get_reader(filename)
for _ in range(reader.get_length()):
    PIL.Image.fromarray(reader.get_next_data().copy()).convert('RGBA')
```

And this is the result when I use a GIF of type A (left, good) versus **type B (right, bad)** for my hug-an-image algorithm:

[image] [image]

Inputs:

[image] [image]

Comment: I'm thinking maybe composing subsequent frames using something like `alpha_composite` might work, but (A) there has to be a simpler way and (B) I don't know how to tell whether a GIF is "difference-based" :/

Comment: The difference-based GIF has the meta-data `'extension': (b'ImageMagick', 822)`, maybe that indicates it is difference-based?

Comment: Relevant [pil-is-showing-all-the-previous-frames-in-the-gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313887/pil-is-showing-all-the-previous-frames-in-the-gif)