# PIL Png With Gif Background

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, gif

I'm trying to make a fortnite image card generator. I want it to make the skin on the top layer and the bg aka the gif on the bottom. Here is the code so far.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

filename = 'CID_613_Athena_Commando_M_Columbus_7Y4QE.png'
skin = Image.open(filename, 'r')
filename1 = 'bg.gif'
bg = Image.open(filename1, 'r')
text_img = Image.new('RGBA', (512,512), (0, 0, 0, 0))
text_img.paste(bg, (0,0))
text_img.paste(skin, (0,0), mask=skin)
text_img.save("out.gif", format="gif")
```

The CID_613_Athena_Commando_M_Columbus_7Y4QE.png is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CaDk.png

Background:
https://i.imgur.com/fCewt2H.gif

And here is the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAAcz.png

I want it to be like animated background. Unlike what it is right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate all frames in the gif and paste the foreground image in all of them.

If the image is animated (`bg.is_animated`), you can get the number of frames in `bg.n_frames`.

For animated images (not just gifs) there Pillow includes a `seek(frame_number)` method that will forward the animation to frame you want to use.

The code will be similar to this:

```py
if bg.is_animated:

  frames = []

  for num in range(bg.n_frames):
    bg.seek(num)
    text_img = Image.new('RGBA', (512,512), (0, 0, 0, 0))
    text_img.paste(bg, (0,0))
    text_img.paste(skin, (0,0), mask=skin)
    frames.append(text_img)

  frames[0].save('out.gif',
                 save_all=True,
                 append_images=frames[1:],
                 duration=100,
                 loop=0)
```

Warning! Pillow does not optimize the gif output. Maybe you need to compress them further with another tool.

If you just need an animation, consider saving to [WEBP file format](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp) just chenge the extension from `.gif` to `.webp` in the `save()` method. You will get a smaller file, it is supported by all browsers, and the image quality is better with gradient backgrounds (there will be no no banding effects due to GIF 8-bit color palette).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do that is without writing any Python and using **ImageMagick** in the Terminal. So, you would load your background GIF and split it into its constituent 72 frames with `-coalesce` then draw the spaceman thing on top and save as animated GIF:

```
magick fCewt2H.gif -coalesce -draw "image SrcOver 0,0 0,0 Seu1Tx6.png" animated.gif
```

[image]

Note that I have decreased the colour quality, number of frames and image size to come in under StackOverflow's 2MB limit for posts. You can get the full quality with the above command.

---

If you do not want to use **ImageMagick** for some reason, you can do it with Python, but you have to appreciate that an animated GIF is one file but **that contains lots of frames**. So you will need to:

- load the foreground frame once (as you do already)
- load the GIF background
- [iterate](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html#image-sequences) over the frames of the background pasting the foreground (you have this code) onto each of the 72 frames
- [save](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55314160/2836621) the resulting 72 frames as a GIF