# Webp images leave trail when converted to gif - Python Pillow

Tags: python, animation, python-imaging-library, gif, webp

Hi there guys so im trying to use the pillow library to make a gif of some images i made in blender. I read that webp supports transparency and animation like gif so I've been trying to make it work in the little snippit i have:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob

# create frames
frames  = []

images = sorted(glob.glob('00*.webp'))
for i in images:
    newFrame = Image.open(i)
    frames.append(newFrame)

# save frames into gif
frames[0].save('render1.webp', format="GIF", append_images=frames[1:], save_all=True, duration=75, loop=0)
```

The gif should look like this but just with a clear background:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgbLz.jpg

That image was made with pngs , the one made with webp images looks like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnUfP.jpg

Any advice or help would be really appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to set the *"disposal"*, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55314160/2836621